# How to implement GROUP_CONCAT in Laravel model class?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm using GROUP_CONCAT function to fetch multiple photo image paths for the selected professional in Laravel. The code is in a model class.
The code segment is as below:

```
$professionals = DB::table('member_professional')
    ->select("member_professional.*",
        DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT photos.picture_path SEPARATOR ',')) as 'photos'"))
    ->join('member','member_professional.member_id_fk','=','member.member_id')
    ->join('photos','photos.member_fk','=','member.member_id')
    ->leftjoin('locations','member.city','=','locations.location_id');

        if ($professionals_type != '') {
                     $professionals = $professionals->where('member_professional.biz_category','=',$professionals_type);
        }

        if ($location != '') {
                     $professionals = $professionals->where('member.city','=',$location);
        }

    $professionals = $professionals->where('member.member_type','=',2); 
    $professionals = $professionals->groupBy('member_professional.member_id_fk')
    ->paginate(20);
```

When I run it on the staging server:  http://dev.interioradditions.pk/allProfessionals it throws the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'interior_dev_db.member_professional.biz_name' isn't in 
>   GROUP BY (SQL: select `member_professional`.*, (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT photos.picture_path SEPARATOR ',')) as 'photos' 
>   from `member_professional` inner join `member` on `member_professional`.`member_id_fk` = `member`.`member_id` inner join `photos` on `photos`.`member_fk` = `member`.`member_id` 
>   left join `locations` on `member`.`city` = `locations`.`location_id` 
>   where `member`.`member_type` = 2 
>   group by `member_professional`.`member_id_fk` limit 20 offset 0)

Whereas when I extract the built sql query from the above statement and execute through PHPMyAdmin it runs fine and gives the result as expected. Please help on getting what's wrong in the Model query.

Thanks!

Comment: You are misusing group by clause

Comment: It would be very easy if you set up models and relationship then eloquent will do rest of the job and there would be no need of `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: Can you please help how to use group by clause for this particular case?

Answer (score 1):

What i prefer going through laravel's approach by defining your models and relationship between them

```
class MemberProfessional extends Model
{  
    public function member()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Member', 'member_id', 'member_id_fk');
    }
}

class Member extends Model
{
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Photos', 'member_fk', 'member_id');
    }    
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Locations', 'location_id', 'city');
    }   
    public function member_professional()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MemberProfessional', 'member_id_fk');
    }   
}

class Photos extends Model{
//...
}

class Locations extends Model{
//...
}
```

And then you could write simple eloquent query

```
$professionals = MemberProfessional::with('member.photos');

if ($professionals_type != '') {
    $professionals = $professionals->where('biz_category','=',$professionals_type);
}

if ($location != '') {
    $professionals->whereHas('member', function ($query) use ($location) {
                $query->where('city', '=', $location);
                  });
}
    $professionals->whereHas('member', function ($query) use ($location) {
                $query->where('member_type', '=', 2);
                  })
                  ->paginate(20);
```

Now for each row you will have collection of related `Photos` model object

Comment: Great. Looks like the best (and clean) solution using Laravel model structure. Sorry for I was busy with some other tasks. Anyways I'll apply this solution and let you know.

Many many thanks for this help. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the new release `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode is by default enabled and you need to use a complete GROUP BY expression like all the columns present in your select list (except aggregated ones) should be present in `GROUP BY` like

```
select a,b, count(c)
from table
group by a,b
```

In your case you need to specify which columns you need from `member_professional` like

```
$professionals = DB::table('member_professional as mp')
    ->select('mp.member_id_fk', 'mp.col1',  'mp.col2',  'mp.col3', DB::raw("(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.picture_path SEPARATOR ',')) as 'photos'"))
    ->join('member as m','mp.member_id_fk','=','m.member_id')
    ->join('photos as p','p.member_fk','=','m.member_id')
    ->leftjoin('locations','m.city','=','locations.location_id');

if ($professionals_type != '') {
    $professionals = $professionals->where('mp.biz_category','=',$professionals_type);
}

if ($location != '') {
    $professionals = $professionals->where('m.city','=',$location);
}
$professionals = $professionals->where('m.member_type','=',2)
    ->groupBy('mp.member_id_fk', 'mp.col1',  'mp.col2',  'mp.col3')
    ->paginate(20);
```

> Also note using GROUP_CONCAT "The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet".